# Flutter: Timer() function is not working in android phone

Tags: android, flutter, api, asynchronous, timer

I have used `Timer(const Duration(seconds:{value of timer}), (){})` (this is not actual code but for exactly showing what function it is) in my flutter application to wait before the data is completely fetched from servers. It is working perfectly in the android emulator, but not in my actual phone.

Answer (score 0):

The timer execute a function every duration (of time). So i think you are using it in the bad way.

To wait for a certain among of time, it is more recommended to make it await (await Future.delayed({yourDuration})) instead.

If i have misundertood your question, feel free to correct me in comment.